# Java - Get integer parts (multiple) of a string and store in one array

Tags: java, regex, split

Consider a string like

```
(42,21) (23,21)
```

I want to get an array from this string like `[42,21,23,21]`

Now I can do that by splitting it 2-3 times and so on.. but i want to know if there is a more efficient way to do it, or say doing it in single line.

Like split a string on everything which is not a number!!

Comment: matching would make more sense then splitting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] numbers = "(42,21) (23,21)".split("\\D+");
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
String[] strings = "2(42,21) (23,21)".split("[^0-9]+");
```

Which means:

> split at every series of chars that aren't numbers